# Codeception still fails when using jsonparser

Tags: codeception

I'm using codeception within a yii2 project. It works fantastic except when I tried to use methods that depends on the flow/jsonpath library. After installing that library in the project, I'm still getting the same issue: "[Exception] JSONPath library not installed. Please add `flow/jsonpath` to composer.json"
I'm running the test from the root of the project in this way: codecept run.

Why I'm still getting the "library not installed" error? I see that in the autoload files from composer, the namespace->path entry exists in the composer files autoload_static.php. Do I need to do another thing after installing a dependency and before running the test? 
Any clue?

Comment: I solved the issue. The problem was that I was generating the suite in a wrong folder. It was at the root level, under test but needed to do under test/codeception, as this is a yii2 basic template project.

Comment: Well... you must be sure that the _boostrap.php, which is configured in the codeception.yml, has the right autoload... if not, the classes in vendor will not be loaded.